# How to obtain USB storage permissions on Android 6+?

Tags: android, android-permissions, usb-drive

I've already obtained this permission:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

save file to local is ok. But I cannot save to `USB` storage device.

How to obtain another write permission?

Comment: The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission only needs to be granted once.

Comment: Yes, it is granted.

Comment: So then what's the problem? They use the same permission.

Comment: Same code saves a file to internal storage is OK. Maybe external storage(sd card, usb) needs another permission to grant.

Comment: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"

Comment: @PrateekBhardwaj think this is a signature-level permission (custom ROM). just see for yourself, it's not listed: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission applications have to request the permission, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`UsbManager.requestPermission()` can be used with a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";

private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if(device != null) {
                      //call method to set up device communication
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
```

which has to be registered:

```
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";

UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);   
mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
```

and then one can request the permission:

```
UsbDevice device;
mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
```

see [USB Host](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host) for how to transfer - and how to `releaseInterface()` and `close()`.

Comment: Let me try it. Thanks.